# Swift - AnyObject[] is not a subtype of AnyObject[]?

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to call an objective C method that takes a block that calls back with an NSArray.

I get the following compile error:

AnyObject[] is not a subtype of AnyObject[]

```
[query fetchPlaces:^(NSArray *places, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Swift

```
query.fetchPlaces() { (places: AnyObject[], error: NSError) -> Void in

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Objective-C, all pointers can be set to `nil`. That means that both `places` and `error` could be `nil`. When converting from Objective-C to Swift, you must take that into account.  You must define `places` and `error` as [Optionals](http://drewag.me/posts/what-is-an-optional-in-swift) to account for the fact that they can be `nil`:

```
query.fetchPlaces() { (places: AnyObject[]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

}
```

If you know for sure that `places` will never be `nil`. You could also declare it as an [Implicitly Unwrapped Optional](http://drewag.me/posts/what-is-an-optional-in-swift#implicitly-unwrapped-optional) letting you treat it as if it were not optional:

```
query.fetchPlaces() { (places: AnyObject[]!, error: NSError?) -> Void in

}
```

**Note:** You must be using an old version of the beta (1 or 2). You should update to the latest beta. Arrays are now declared as `[SomeType]` not `SomeType[]`

Comment: Thanks for the last note. I was actually confused that the syntax from docs was not working, but the syntax I guessed did :)

Answer (score 3):

In objective-c any object can be nil, but in Swift this must be declared explicitly.  In converting ObjC to Swift, all Objective-C objects become optionals.  Try:

```
query.fetchPlaces() { (places: AnyObject[]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

}
```